# Duplicate woocommerce-cart-form and cart_totals when updating cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin. when I try to update cart after added cart, all data is showing duplicity each time. I used woocommerce default cart template

[image: Cart Form Screenshot]

[image: Cart Total Screenshot]

Comment: How can this be answered without seeing the code?

Comment: You should always add the related code in your question. Without it nobody can guess and help you.

Comment: it's just default cart.php file

Comment: i just fixed that issue usinig this js :)

  $( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
      jQuery(".woocommerce-cart-form:first-child").remove();
      jQuery(".cart_totals:first-child").remove();      
  });